# Are existing CSS properties reapplied if i overwritte a className in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Lets say i have the following CSS classes.

```
.div{
background-color: #eee;
}
.show{
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
}
.hide{
top: -50%;
left: -50%;
}
```

and now i create a div and set its classname with Javascript.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.className = "div"
```

later on i change it again to

```
div.className = "div show";
```

and then again to

```
div.className = "div hide";
```

It seems to me that if i work in this way i will have set the background-color of this div 3 times to #eee no? If this is true; would it not be more economic to just adjust the top and left coordinates with javascript instead? Like so?

```
div.style.top = "50%";
div.style.left = "50%";
```

Also if this is true i might as well use the following CSS classes No?

```
.divShow{
background-color: #eee;
top:50%;
left:50%;
}
.divHide{
background-color: #eee;
top:-50%;
left:-50%;
}
```

Or am i understanding CSS all wrong?

Comment: why don't you check it by yourself??

Comment: _"i will have set the background-color of this div 3 times"_ -> This is implementation specific and is a browser thing.  I would hope they're clever enough to realise that the `div` class hasn't changed so wouldn't change it, but who knows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check for the `Element.prototype.classList` property. It offers you methods like `.add()`, `.remove()` and even `.toggle()`. You also can apply multiple class names with those methods.

```
div.classList.add( 'div' );
```

[MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score 1):

Setting className in JS OVERWRITES the class name.

Each time you change class name (like from div show to div hide) you are removing the class of div and show, then re-adding the class of div, and adding to class of hide.

There is nothing un-economic about this, as you aren't directly setting css to the element.

Also, you can't set a parameter more than once, it just overwrites the previous setting (so it's not un-economic, don't worry).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong way to add a class. When you use `div.className`, you are overwriting the class, applying the `background` property several times.

You should use `div.classList.add( 'div' );` instead

Answer (score 0):

Its like a changing values of a variable if

you write

```
   var div = document.getElementById("div");
   div.className = "classname";
```

then i will give replace the classname of div element with last assigned value

but if your write

```
 var div = document.getElementById("div");
div.className += " classname";
```

then it will add the class to div element